# c# Static List of class/struct Objects

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, struct

I'm playing around with Unity, but I'm not very famliar with C#. 
I think what I want is fairly easy, but not beeing a native english speaker I'm missing the right keywords to search for it, i guess.

What I want is a class (or struct?) that just collects a few bits of data:

```
public class Biome {
    string name;
    Color color;
    float base height; (...)
}
```

Then I want a predefined list of objects to this. Like Ocean, Meadow, Forest. Those should be easily accessible in code, as I will need the information a lot. At best they would be accessible by their names, if that is possible. Also I want the list to be displayable in a Unity editor, so that I may change the values (adjusting the color and such).

How do I do this or is there a name for it, so that I can successfully search for it?

Comment: When you say a predefined list of objects, what do you mean exactly? Are these objects instances of the Biome class or are they members of the Biome class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the serializable tag on your class and create public members of that type. Now when you add the component to a game object and select it in the hierarchy, your data will be editable in the inspector. For example -

```
public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Declare your serializable data
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Biome {
        public string name;
        public Color color;
        public float height;
    }

    // Create public members of your custom type
    public Biome Ocean;
    public Biome Meadow;
    public Biome Forest;
    ...

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have static members ? Like with the Colors class of C# where Colors is the class and Colors.Black is allways the same? Is static members even the right word for that? 
I really have problems finding the right keywords to even search for stuff.

Comment: Yes you can also have `static` OR `const` members which you can access like Colors.Black. Remember a `const` member is always static. So you specify a member as either `static` or `const` not both together.